# Discriminate between empty and non empty regexp matches in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to match some strings in Matlab and create a new table from the matches.

The variable `txt` contains:

```
  Columns 1 through 4

    'Time'    'LR1R2'    'LR1R2_SD'    'LR1R2_I'

  Columns 5 through 8

    'LR1R2_SD'    'R1'    'R1_SD'    'R1_I'

  Columns 9 through 12

    'R1_I_SD'    'R2'    'R2_SD'    'R2_I'

  Column 13

    'R2_I_SD'
```

And I want to select all those with `'_SD'` on the end of the string

```
pattern='_SD';
match=regexp(txt,pattern)
```

which returns:

```
match = 

  Columns 1 through 8

    []    []    [6]    []    [6]    []    [3]    []

  Columns 9 through 13

    [5]    []    [3]    []    [5]
```

Does anybody know how to discriminate between the empty and non empty matches? My aim is to build a new table from the matches. Here is what I've tried

```
for i=match,
    ~isempty(i)
end
```

But this returns true for everything.

Thanks

Comment: Expected output would be a a cell array with endings as `_SD`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`regexp`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) function returns a cell array, where each cell contains either an empty array (i.e. `[]`), or a number (e.g. `[6]`). To go through all cells of this cell array, you can use the [`cellfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) function and apply the `isempty` function to each cell:

```
~cellfun(@isempty,match)
```

which returns

```
ans =
     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
```

As @Divakar correctly remarks, using

```
~cellfun('isempty',match)
```

is much faster.
When the command is run 100'000 times, I measured the following run times:

With `@isempty`:

```
Elapsed time is 0.757626 seconds.
```

With `'isempty'`:

```
Elapsed time is 0.118241 seconds.
```

Note that this syntax is not available for all functions. From the MATLAB documentation on `cellfun`:

> `cellfun` accepts function name strings for function `func`, rather than a
>   function handle, for these function names: `isempty`, `islogical`, `isreal`,
>   `length`, `ndims`, `prodofsize`, `size`, `isclass`. Enclose the function name in
>   single quotes.

Comment: `~cellfun('isempty',match)` might be faster, being a built-in.

Comment: @Divakar thanks for the hint, I didn't know about that. And it already gives a speed-up of about 7x.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for is something like:

```
for i=1:length(match),
    if ~isequal(match(i),{[]}),
        num(:,i)
    end
end
```

As hbaderts suggested the following is also a way to do this:

```
~cellfun(@isempty,match)
```